# Import in a .jsp file

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee

I have a big project and the import doesn't work. 
I have something like :

**project\banana1\banana2\banana3\banana4\myFile**

And

**project\foo1\foo2\foo3\myClasses**

I want to do an import of *myClasses* into *myFile*

Now, I  have something like :

```
<%@ page import="foo1.foo2.foo3.*" %>
```

But it doesn't work and I don't know how to refer to an other file like that. Help please !

Comment: Do you get an exception when rendering your JSP? if you do put the stack trace plz.

Comment: can u please elaborate your question why import does not work ?